# Terminology concerning a certain solution to a certain system of equations

Tags: terminology, contest-math

Say you have a solution $\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ to a system of equations. It turns out that  $-\textbf{x}$ is also a solution. Is there accepted terminology for such a pair of solutions? (I don't think *conjugate* is it.) Is there terminology for the system that admits such solutions? (I don't think *symmetric* is general enough.)

Assume we're dealing with real numbers here.

Comment: I don't think there is. Were I in that position, I'd just say that system so-and-so has solutions $\mathbf x=(\pm x_1,\dots,\pm x_n)$.

Comment: @J.M., your notation implies $(x_1,-x_2,x_3,...)$  is a solution, which is not what OP has written.

Comment: My initial instinct was to call them "antipodal," but that only really works if the points are confined to a sphere.  Yes, implicitly $\textbf{x}$ and $-\textbf{x}$ are on the same sphere with origin $0$, and they are antipodal on that sphere, but I think that's a stretch of the term.

Comment: @Thomas: probably with the qualifier "with same upper signs or lower signs..." then.

Comment: @J.M.: Not clear why you wouldn't just write that as $\pm \textbf{x}$

Comment: I suppose that's less confusing @Thomas. :)

Comment: "Symmetric by reflection across the origin" or some variant.

Comment: Maybe we can term them "mirror solutions"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard in calculus would be "symmetric with respect to the origin" or "symmetric by reflection in the origin" or some variant.